# amdgpu-dkms error installing AMD Radeon driver on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu, 23.04

Are proprietary drivers for amd possible on 23.04?

Driver Title: Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 23.10.2 for Ubuntu 22.04.2

Driver revision number: 23.10.2

Install:

```
~/Downloads$ amdgpu-install
...
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:6.0.5.50502-1607507.22.04) ...
Removing old amdgpu-6.0.5-1607507.22.04 DKMS files...
Deleting module amdgpu-6.0.5-1607507.22.04 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new amdgpu-6.0.5-1607507.22.04 DKMS files...
Building for 6.2.0-25-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.2.0-25-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-25-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

make.log

```
...
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c: In function ‘amdgpufb_create’:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c:236:16: error: implicit declaration of function ‘drm_fb_helper_alloc_fbi’; did you mean ‘drm_fb_helper_alloc_info’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  236 |         info = drm_fb_helper_alloc_fbi(helper);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                drm_fb_helper_alloc_info
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c:236:14: warning: assignment to ‘struct fb_info *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  236 |         info = drm_fb_helper_alloc_fbi(helper);
      |              ^
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c:264:73: error: ‘struct drm_mode_config’ has no member named ‘fb_base’
  264 |         info->apertures->ranges[0].base = adev_to_drm(adev)->mode_config.fb_base;
      |                                                                         ^
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_benchmark.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/atombios_dp.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_afmt.o
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c: In function ‘amdgpu_fbdev_destroy’:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.c:306:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘drm_fb_helper_unregister_fbi’; did you mean ‘drm_fb_helper_unregister_info’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  306 |         drm_fb_helper_unregister_fbi(&rfbdev->helper);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         drm_fb_helper_unregister_info
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:260: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_fb.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:512: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build/amd/amdgpu] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:2026: /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.0.5-1607507.22.04/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.0-25-generic'
```

Comment: welcome to the AMD team, is the worst trash of all :/ I have a 6750 xt and the bugs and reinstall drivers are my day to day, please guys dont wasted money in AMD :/

Comment: I have the same issue - seems that the only (theoretical at least) option is to go to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS since it is officially supported by AMD.